# how the switch and case matches in c?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have the following code in c:

```
typedef enum
{
  Filter_NAME,
  Filter_NAME_2,
  Filter_NAME_3         
} Filter;


void printInfo(int filter)
{
   switch()
   {
      case Filter_NAME:
         // code part1
      case Filter_NAME_2:
         // code part2
      case Filter_NAME_3:
         // code part3
      default:
         return;    
   }
}

void main()
{
   int filter = Filter_NAME;
   printInfo(filter);
   return 0;
}
```

I only want the `code part1` executed, but the `code part1` `code part2` and `code part3` all executed, what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: [what is break in switch?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx).

Comment: You need to say `switch(filter)` and you probably want some `break` statements.

Comment: `switch` is a very primitive structure which is effectively a repeated `if (switchVar == caseNValue) goto caseNLabel;`.  Control "falls through" across the `case` clauses.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add `break` after each `case` block.

```
void printInfo(int filter)
{
   switch(filter)
   {
      case Filter_NAME:
         // code part1
         break;
      case Filter_NAME_2:
         // code part2
         break;
      case Filter_NAME_3:
         // code part3
         break;
      default:
         return;    
   }
}
```

This will stop propagation into the other case blocks, and it will jump to the end of the `switch` statement.

Comment: The program jumps to the `case` that matches the value in `switch` and then continues running from there. It will not automatically skip other `case`s. That's what `break;` is used for, it jumps out of the current `case` branch. This behavior can be useful when two values should result in executing the same code block.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add 'break' after each part.then only if part 1 satisfies then it executes part1 and then terminates.otherwise all cases will be executed

Answer (score 0):

The [C99 standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards.html) document, section 6.8.4.2 briefs about the working of switch and case. You could perhaps refer that for what is syntactically/semantically correct.